# Avoid allocation of abstract type with templates

Tags: c++, templates, abstract-class, allocation, c++98

**The context:** I wrote some tools for archiving data, in a similar way of archives from boost. Then, as example, I can write this kind of code :

```
class A
{
  private:
    double a;
  public:
    A() : a(3.14159)
    {}
    A(const A& a_) : a(a_.a) {}
    virtual ~A()
    {}
    virtual A* clone() const = 0; // Then, A is virtual

    virtual void save(O_Archive& oa) const  //
    {                                       // 
      oa << this->a;                        // INTERESTING
    }                                       // PART OF THE
    virtual void load(I_archive& ia)        //    CLASS
    {                                       //
      ia >> this->a;                        //
    }                                       //
};
O_Archive& operator << (O_Archive& oa, const A& a)
{
  a.save(oa);
  return oa;
}
I_Archive& operator >> (I_Archive& ia, A& a)
{
  a.load(ia);
  return ia;
}

class B : public A
{
  private:
    double b;
  public:
    B() : A(), b(1.0) {}
    B(const B& b_) : A(b_), b(b_.b) {}
    virtual ~B() {}
    virtual A* clone() const
    {
      return new B(*this);
    }

    void save(O_Archive& oa) const  //
    {                               //
      this->A::save(oa);            //
      oa << this->b;                // INTERESTING
    }                               // PART OF THE
    void load(I_Archive& ia)        //    CLASS
    {                               //
      this->A::load(ia);            //
      ia >> this->b;                //
    }                               //
};

// Consider classes 'C' and 'D' similar to 'B'

void example_save(O_Archive& oa)
{
  A* p1 = new B;
  A* p2 = new C;
  D* p3 = new D;
  oa << Archive::declare_derived<A,B,C,D>();
  oa << p1 << p2; // Automatically detect the inheritance
  oa << p3; // Store the instance as a usual pointer
}
void example_load(I_Archive& ia)
{
  A* p1 = 0;
  A* p2 = 0;
  B* p3 = 0;
  ia << Archive::declare_derived<A,B,C,D>();
  ia >> p1 >> p2;
  ia >> p3;
}
```

**Where is the problem ?** This works with several functions like the following `load_pointer` function in the class `I_Archive` in charge of checking if the pointer was allocated, if it was an instance with a derived type, or simply a usual pointer.

```
template <typename T>
void I_Archive::load_pointer(T*& p)
{
    delete p;
    bool allocated;
    this->load_bool(allocated);
    if(allocated)
    {
        bool inheriance;
        this->load_bool(inheriance);
        if(inheriance)
        {
            unsigned long int i;
            this->load_unsigned_long_int(i);
            p = boost::static_pointer_cast< const Archive::allocator<T> >(this->alloc[&typeid(T)][i])->allocate();
        }
        else
            p = new T;  // ERROR AT THIS LINE
        *this >> *p;
    }
    else
        p = 0;
}
```

**My problem:** Actually, my code doesn't compile with the following error on the line `p = new T;` :

> error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘A’.

I was first surprised, but **I really well understand why I have this error** : when the function `load_pointer` is called on `p1`, the instruction `new T` becomes `new A` which is forbidden, even if the instruction is never run if the type is abstract.

**My question:** I can't find a way to correctly use templates to avoid my error. Is there a possible workaround to do that or to say to the compiler *"I know what I'm doing, you'll never have to instanciate an abstract type"* ?

**Important note:** I can't work with C++11 for compatibility reason.

Comment: It appears type `T` in failing case is `A`.

Comment: Maybe you could simply overload your `load_pointer` function for the special case of A in which you can put the stuff specific to A.

Comment: @ThomasBenard : it's not the responsability of `Archive` to know all the abstract classes of the application. It implies that I would have to edit the `Archive` class each time I add a new abstract class. It's a very bad design.

Comment: I agree on that ;) So basically, what you trying to do is to do something in some cases and something else in other cases, right ? That is what inheritance exists for, not templates I would say.

Comment: You could probably use `boost::is_abstract` or if you don't want to use boost - then try to steal its [guts](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/boost/type_traits/is_abstract.hpp)

Comment: I understand that you want to be able to store an object of a derived class (through a base class pointer) and later load it back and affect it to a pointer to a base class. But on shown code I cannot understand **how** you save the actual type of the object and how you intend to use that information to create an object of correct type.

Comment: @Rostislav: I don't understand how `is_abstract` can solve the problem. If i write `if(!is_abstract(T)) p = new T;` the compiler give me the same error (of course).

Comment: @SergeBallesta : It's not really a matter, because this part is working fine. The idea is the following. The derivation declaration fills two objects with types `std::map<std::type_info const*, std::vector<std::type_info const*>>>` and `std::map<std::type_info const*, std::vector<basic_allocator*>>>` from the template parameters. When I save the pointer, I store the index of the real type, when I load it, I know I can make a `static_cast` to the base class on the result of the `basic_allocator`. I can add the code in my question if you want, but it's quite complex.

Comment: My question would be, as you are able to build dynamically a derived type using an Allocator, why cannot you use same way to build a non derived type?

Comment: @Caduchon With a [trivial](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) implementation of `enable_if` and some overloading it can be done like [this](http://rextester.com/JSTI4343). You would need `typename std::enable_if<...>::type` of course.

Comment: [this](http://rextester.com/YYT34589) is slightly cleaner.

Comment: @SergeBallesta : the allocators are generated by the call `ia << Archive::delcalre_derived<BaseClass,Derived1,Derived2,...>();`. It's possible to use a similar way, but then I have to force the user to call somthing like `ia << Archive::declare_not_derived<MyOtherClass>();`. It's a possibility, but it's not a perfect solution.

Comment: @Rostislav : it looks like a good idea. I will try it. I suppose I have to use the boost version instead of std ? I'm not using c++11.

Comment: Yup, that's why I mentioned boost in the first place.

Comment: @Rostislav : It's working fine. Thanks ! If you add it as answer, I'll validate it.

Comment: Done. And happy to help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trait you're looking for is `std::is_abstract`. As you mentioned, you cannot use C++11, but you can use its [implementation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/boost/type_traits/is_abstract.hpp) from boost.

You can then use `is_abstract` together with `std::enable_if` (again, due to your restriction of not using C++11, you can just take the example implementation from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if)) to implement it similarly to this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct A {
    virtual void f() = 0;
};

struct B : A {
    void f() override {}
};


template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_abstract<T>::value, T*> allocate()
{
    return nullptr;
}

template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<!std::is_abstract<T>::value, T*> allocate()
{
    return new T;
}

// Test
template<typename T>
T* test_alloc()
{
    return allocate<T>();
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << test_alloc<A>() << "\n"; // Outputs nullptr
    std::cout << test_alloc<B>() << "\n"; // Outputs an address
}
```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/YYT34589)